# Consolidating specific values in multidimensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have an array of arrays consisting of date, login name, and time (length of time in ms). Here is what it vaguely looks like:

```
[0]=>
     [0]=> "2015-09-06"
     [1]=> "user1"
     [2]=> "8947226"
[1]=>
     [0]=> "2015-09-06"
     [1]=> "user1"
     [2]=> "6664923"
[2]=>
     [0]=> "2015-09-24"
     [1]=> "user2"
     [2]=> "654654"
```

I'm trying to make it so that if the date and the login are both the same as another, it adds the time together. So it will look like:

```
[0]=>
     [0]=> "2015-09-06"
     [1]=> "user1"
     [2]=> "15612149"
[1]=>
     [0]=> "2015-09-24"
     [1]=> "user2"
     [2]=> "654654"
```

I think my main problem is how to search the array because they won't necessarily be in order by date or login, they're all random.
First I was doing this because I thought they would be in some sort of order:

```
    if ($i != 0) { 
        if ($date == $bigArray[$prevIndex][0] && $login == $bigArray[$prevIndex][1]) { 

            $bigArray[$prevIndex][2] += $time; 

        } else { 

            array_push($bigArray, array($date, $login, $time));

            $prevIndex++;

        }

    } else { 

        array_push($bigArray, array($date, $login, $time)); 


    }
```

But that doesn't work since they are in a random order. I've tried to sort the array first as well, and that's not working.

Comment: What have you done so far? Please post your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a way to do it, but maybe it's not the best.

```
<?php

$arr = [];
$arr[0] = ["2015-09-26", "user1", "8947226"];
$arr[1] = ["2015-09-26", "user1", "6664923"];
$arr[2] = ["2015-09-24", "user2", "654654"];

// Variable to store the new values.
$arr2 = [];

// Scrolls through the array
foreach($arr as $ar) {

   // Creates a key to identify date and login
   $key = md5($ar[0].$ar[1]);

   // Checks whether the value is already in the variable $arr2
   if (isset($arr2[ $key ])) {

      // If so, adds the values in ms
      $arr2[ $key ][2] += $ar[2];
   } else {
      $arr2[ $key ] = $ar;
   }
}

// Use the array_values to display only the values (without displaying the $key);
var_export( array_values($arr2) );
```